# Magento 2.4.2 How to add Key Features to the product detail page

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, custom-options, product-page, magento2.4.2

I need to add Key Features to the product detail page.The function should be a new attribute, but I don't know how to add it. Do you have a simple and quick way.

Key Features can be replaced with any content.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a Multi Select product attribute which you would populate with all possible options. When you create this attribute, you need to make sure that **Storefront Properties > Used in Product Listing** is set to YES.  And then you would select which features apply on product level.

Then you can simply add a new block to your `catalog_product_view.xml`. If you need to do complicated logic, you should create a block class for it, but its not necessary for simple output of product attribute.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" after="product.info.overview" name="product.features" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/features.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

And your template to output could look like this in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/product/view/features.phtml` - in this example your attribute code is **product_features**

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$product = $block->getProduct();
$baseUrl = $block->getBaseUrl();

  if ($product->getProductFeatures()):
      $productFeatures = $product->getAttributeText('product_features');
       // if only one option selected then it will be returned as string
       // so we need to transform to array for the foreach loop
      if (!is_array($productFeatures)) {
        $productFeatures = [$productFeatures];
      } ?>

<div class="product-features">
    <?php foreach ($productFeatures as $feature):
        $featureUrl = $baseUrl.'media/icons/features/'.str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($feature)).'.png'; ?>
      <span class="feature">
        <img class="product-feature-icon"
          alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__($feature)) ?>"
          src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($featureUrl) ?>" />
          <span class="name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($feature) ?></span>
      </span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, you could create the icons for each feature in a media folder and name each image as the options name. e.g. 'Polarized' becomes `pub/media/icons/features/polarized.png`

Answer (score 0):

To create a new attribute *(I assume a textarea with WYSIWYG enabled would be nice)*, go to your module, and create a new patch in the location `Vendor/module-name/Setup/Patch/Data/AddKeyFeaturesAttribute.php` with the following content:

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class AddKeyFeaturesAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    const KEY_FEATURES_ATTRIBUTE_CODE = 'key_features';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $dataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetup
     */
    private $eavSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $dataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $dataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->dataSetup       = $dataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavSetup        = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->dataSetup]);
    }

    /**
     * Apply the patch
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->dataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

        $this->createNewProductAttribute();

        $this->dataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Get array of patches that have to be executed prior to this
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get aliases (previous names) for the patch
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Create new product attribute key_features
     */
    protected function createNewProductAttribute()
    {
          $attributeData = [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Key Features',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'searchable' => false,
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'wysiwyg_enabled' => true
        ];

        $this->eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            self::KEY_FEATURES_ATTRIBUTE_CODE,
            $attributeData
        );
    }
}
```

Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` afterwards and check your attribute and assign it to the attribute set you need it to go into in the admin area.

Comment: Thanks Diana Botean. I follow your method, and I can’t see the attribute key features in the admin area.

Comment: You have to add it into your desired attribute set first.